# New to SQL Server Membership database

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership

I'm new to membership and providers. I just have seen a video and its basic understanding.

I am using Visual Studio 2008. I was able to attach DB in project.

1. Why it is not being shown in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?
2. How I will transfer this DB into commercial environment? Should I have another DB for this?
3. I'm using Asp.Net configuration application/tool. In video(using Visual Studio 2010) it was being shown that it added a connection string in web.config and a new DB was added into SQL Server.

I need some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the question - " how I will transfer this db into commercial environment ? Should I have another db for this ? "

You can achieve this by creating a script of you DB, which will contain the DB schema( and it can also the present data in the DB in the script, optinally if you want). Then run this script on your production server to create the DB over there.

Have look at this link for [Creating the Membership Schema in SQL Server](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs)

Answer (score 1):

1) to access it through SSMS, you'll probably have to attach the database file to the server explorer. 
2) depending upon your host, you could upload the same db-file , and then just change the connection string accordingly and then use it. **OR** you could generate a back-up script of your database and use it to populate your new database(provided by your host).
3) for this, I'll have to see the video myself to exactly figure out what's happening. Most probably, the connection string provided was of the SQL server itself, rather than the new db file attached to your project.

Comment: "Most probably, the connection string provided was of the SQL server itself, rather than the new db file attached to your project."

But as I mentioned there is no connection string in web.config. Can you please guide where connectionstring is stored ? and why not it is stored in web.config as default ?